# tutorial turtlebot-simulator-desktop broken

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I've successfully installed "ROS Groovy" on "Ubuntu Precise".
I'm following the tutorials -- which are very helpful, by the way! -- but I got stuck at
turtlebot_simulator /
Tutorials /
Installing TurtleBot Simulator

```
Not a link to avoid the karma censors:
www DOT ros DOT org /wiki/turtlebot_simulator/Tutorials/Installing%20TurtleBot%20Simulator
```

Step 2.4 says to install some software: "apt-get install ros-electric-turtlebot-simulator-desktop", but that package does not exist.  Indeed, "apt-cache search" finds only one package with "turtlebot-simulator" in the name: ros-fuerte-turtlebot-simulator

But I'm running "groovy".  Is it
advisable to install something
containg "fuerte" in the package
name?

Continuing on to the next tutorial part

```
www DOT ros DOT org/wiki/turtlebot_simulator/Tutorials/Running%20the%20Simulator
```

Step 2 is to launch the simulation.  I do have package "ros-groovy-simulator-gazebo" installed, but the command fails:

```
$ roslaunch turtlebot_gazebo turtlebot_empty_world.launch
[turtlebot_gazebo] is not a package or launch file name
```

What are the packages / commands appropriate for "ROS Groovy"?

Thanks,
-Steve

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/64629/tutorial-turtlebot-simulator-desktop-broken/) by [Steve Robbins](https://answers.ros.org/users/5099/steve-robbins/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-06-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi !

If you are running Groovy on your computer, then you either might be following the wrong tutorial or the tutorial hasn't been updated.
Anyway, you mentionned you wanted to install : apt-get install *ros-electric-turtlebot-simulator-desktop*

which mentions ros-electric version. if this package does exist for Groovy, then you should replace *electric* by *groovy* in the package name.

By the way, with ROS groovy, the Turtlebot simulator hasn't been released yet (see Robot, Turtlebot tutorials for more informations). So I wonder where you did find this tutorial ? You can still try kobuki simulator, but it doesn't seem to work very well (have a look on ROS answers) for some users...

---

Originally posted by [Lucile](https://answers.ros.org/users/4897/lucile/) with karma: 318 on 2013-06-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Steve Robbins](https://answers.ros.org/users/5099/steve-robbins/) on 2013-06-10**:
Where did I find this tutorial?  I started at the beginning of the tutorials and ran through all the Beginner Tutorials, ending with #20: "Where Next?" (http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/WhereNext).  Part 1.1 includes links to the PR2 Simulator and the Turtlebot Simulator.

**Comment by [Lucile](https://answers.ros.org/users/4897/lucile/) on 2013-06-10**:
Ok... Well those tutorials are outdated for groovy and precise. You can't use them as they are with your current ROS version. :-s